# Что нужно, чтобы подключить c++ либу в проект Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c++, xamarin

Есть некая либа на плюсах. Есть 3 библиотеки-обертки над ней для использования в ios, android и UWP.

Вопрос: как всё это добро перенести в Xamarin? Надо подключать в каждый проект свою обертку или можно как-то сделать одну общую сразу для всех?

Answer (score 1):

Тут уже смотря на задействованные компоненты. Если задействована только бизнес логика расчетов и т.д., то подключайте в Core проект. Если идет задействование внутренних компонентов системы (система хранения, конвертации специфических объектов, таких как изображения) устанавливайте в каждый проект.

Пример реализации плагинов для Xamarin рассмотрен тут (хоть и для С#)
https://blog.xamarin.com/creating-reusable-plugins-for-xamarin-forms/

Доступные плагины для Xamarin (можете посмотреть структуру проектов)
https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents#create-a-plugin-for-xamarin